# FB.api() on localhost behave different between chrome and FF

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I don't know if my setup is messed-up or I miss something on my code, I've setup FB-JavaScript-SDK:

```
<script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId      : 'APP_ID',
                // cookie     : true,
                // xfbml      : true,
                version    : 'v3.2'
            });

            FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
        };

        (function(d, s, id){
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
```

And call login function like below:

```
FB.login(function(r) {
            console.log(r);
            if (r.status === 'connected') {
                // success login send data to server
                FB.api('/me', { access_token: 'TOKEN' }, function(r) {
                    console.log(r)
                });
            }
        }, { scope: 'public_profile,email,user_birthday,user_photos' });
```

And I got different result between FF and Chrome:

1. FF

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/me?access_token=TOKEN&method=get&pretty=0&sdk=joey&suppress_http_code=1.
>   (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

2. Chrome

> {name: "Tyler Alckfbdjeadc Adeagbowitz", id: "USER_ID"}

Why I got CORS on FF but not on Chrome, it's make frustrated now.

Comment: are you sure you are using a webserver with localhost, and not just open the html file in a browser instead?

Comment: yes, I use https://localhost